# What is my share of a SAAS startup that I developed the whole software from scratch as a partner?

Tags: software-development, startup, business

A friend suggested an idea to me so we could use it in a startup company. The idea is to develop a SAAS and sell it online.

**I will do the development from A to Z**. He is responsible for marketing, studying the market, and doing a valid business model along with searching for investors.

The question is that we want to register the company, I want to know what my share of the company should be.

Is it going to be 50-50? Or what?

Thanks!

Comment: Does your friend actually have any formal skills in the areas they will be working in?

Comment: Yes, he does have a couple of years working in the business and strategies planning field.

Comment: Food for thought: if his business skills are so great, and the idea so fantastic, why would he give up 50% of it to someone instead of saving money/taking a loan, whatever to get the pre-seed funding and keep 100% of it? They reached out for free labor for a reason. Like... If software is so amazing but all it needs is funding, it is not unheard for getting sales that fund development, even before 1 line of code is written, and then leveraging that into funding.

Comment: Here is a link to the QA of a similar question on this site: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/171522/job-offer-with-equity-from-a-startup-what-to-look-for?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

> Is it going to be 50-50? Or what?

It is up to the 2 of you to work it out.

Most co-founders split the shares even among themselves when everyone contributes approximately a similar amount of hard work and innovations that translate to the success of the products.

It is important that all co-founders get recognized properly for their contributions. Otherwise, the startup may fail very soon in case of disagreement among the founders.

Comment: Not being a business guy, I do not know the offers and work that he will put in, but I certainly know the offers I will be making, which are huge and this will take 3-4 months of working to build the app. But he is the founder of the idea though.

Comment: @Moayad.AlMoghrabi, I do see the difficulty you have in evaluating the share distributions since you are a developer and not in the marketing business. But, if he can bring in lots of good investors, his contributions would be significant.

Comment: Great, so 50/50 would be fair for both of us in this scenario, no?

Comment: This product is his idea. Do you think his idea is a wonderful one that will bring great success ? Also, do you think he has great business skills in his past work so far that can bring lots of good investors ? Does he show you a good road map or practical plan of how he plans to market the product and attract investors ?

Comment: It is a wonderful idea. I know he has good skills, but whether they are great or not, I am not fully sure. By saying that, do you mean this is a main factor, and maybe it will determine if he deserves more or less than 50%?

Answer (score 1):

What is "fair" depends on each person's perception of how much value they are bringing to the table and how much they are willing to negotiate. There is no abstract rule for this; what is fair is what the two of you agree is fair.

Nobody else's opinion really matters. Appealing to authority (or to random opinions on the internet) will probably not help you reach this agreement. We have no way of evaluating the value of those contributions, or predicting the value of the proposed product, or odds of its successful completion or its success in the market. We may have opinions, but they're no more likely to be valid than yours are.

Note that there is no guarantee that you can reach such an agreement. In which case you respectfully agree to disagree, wish each other well, and walk away.

Whatever you do, get it on paper; verbal agreements are unenforceable as well as being prone to misunderstanding. You may want to hire a lawyer. You may *each* want to hire a lawyer, to avoid conflict of interest.

Good luck.